# PostgreSQL Hot Standby

Tags: postgresql, replication, standby

I have two PostgreSQL servers running on my local Ubuntu machine (port 5437 is master, port 5438 is standby).

While following the tutorial on
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hot_Standby

I get this in my log2:

```
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2013-02-23 20:48:03 PST
LOG:  creating missing WAL directory "pg_xlog/archive_status"
LOG:  entering standby mode
LOG:  restored log file "000000010000000000000002" from archive
LOG:  redo starts at 0/2000020
LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/20000C4
LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
cp: cannot stat `/home/ga/p1/000000010000000000000003': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `/home/ga/p1/000000010000000000000003': No such file or directory
```

and the last line repeats indefinitely ...

The file is missing. With WAL, when would the new file be created?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like PostgreSQL is set to recover from log shipping rather than by connecting as a replication user.  Please double and triple check your recovery.conf and if that doesn't work, then post it here.

The approach you are taking is a valid approach though, and it means that the recovery will just wait for the next segment until it arrives creating the message you are seeing, but it must be transferred using whatever recovery command you have configured in the master's postgresql.conf.